# How to deserialize json string to different specific java Objec？

Tags: java, serialization, gson, deserialization

I managed to serialize an extreme complex class (which nests 50-some customize java object) to json string using gson.
Here is a piece of my object:

```java
public class MyComplexObject{
     private int a;
     private String b;
     private MyclassA c;
     ...
     private map<String, Object> x;
}
```

Please note that with the field `private map<String, Object> x`, the VALUE `Object` could be `Integer`,`Double`, `String`, `myClassC`, etc....
It works well when serializing, but when deserializing, gson could not convert the json string according to my expectation.

MyClassC:

```
public class MyclassC{
    public String d;
    public List<Integer> e;
}
```

Here is an example:

```
MyComplexObject myComplexObject = new MyComplexObject();
myComplexObject.seta(1);
myComplexObject.setb("abc");

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
MyClassC myClassC = new MyClassC("key1", list);
myComplexObject.setx(myClassC);

// Serializing and Deserializing
String myComplexObjectStr = gson.toJson(myComplexObject);
MyComplexObject myComplexObject2 = gson.fromJson(myComplexObjectStr, MyComplexObject.class);

// after deserializing, x has been converted to LinkedTreeMap
myComplexObject.x.getClass();   // class MyClassC
myComplexObject2.x.getClass();   // class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap

// Go further about the field x

Object object = myComplexObject2.x.get("key1");

LinkedTreeMap linkedTreeMap = (LinkedTreeMap) object;
ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList) linkedTreeMap.get("e");

arrayList.get(0).getClass(); // class java.lang.Double
```

So after serializing and deserializing:

1. MyClassC was converted to LinkedTreeMap
2. List<Integer> was converted to List<Double>

So my question is: What should I do to ensure `MyComplexObject` to be identical completely after serialization and deserialization?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal verifiable example? Normally you shouldn't have to do more than simply specifying the types in your Java class. For your example, that would be something like `public class MyClass { public Integer keyA; }`. If you're not restricted to GSON, you could also consider [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (popular in Spring but also EE) or even [yasson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson) (the reference implementation of the JSON-B EE standard).

Comment: I've update my post to describe it clearly, Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

When deserializing a JSON number with Gson as `Object`, it defaults to deserializing the JSON value as Java `Double` (as you have seen). Recently in Gson 2.8.9 a new feature has been added which allows specifying a [`ToNumberStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/ToNumberStrategy.html). This allows you to more easily influence how Gson deserializes JSON numbers. Some default implementations are provided by the `ToNumberPolicy` enum. The one closest to your requirement is [`ToNumberPolicy.LONG_OR_DOUBLE`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/ToNumberPolicy.html#LONG_OR_DOUBLE). If you really need `Integer` as value type, you can try writing your own implementation similar to [Gson's one](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ffcfb15f6c63548f2d10a945116df8d5dbb8a025/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/ToNumberPolicy.java#L67-L80).

Comment: I'll have a try, thank you!

Comment: I managed to write my  ToNumberPolicy.INTEGER_OR_DOUBLE implementation and it works, thank you again!

Comment: @cspeng1, no problem. Could you please [mark my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate that this question has been answered?